# How can I set up a VPN client on a DD-WRT router behind another router?

Tags: home-networking

I recently subscribed to a VPN service and was wondering if it is possible to set up the dd-wrt router so that any connections to a virtual wireless network go through the VPN. Can this still be done even though the router is basically configured as a switch behind another router? If so, how?

Comment: This entirely depends on if the service supports OpenVPN.  In other words the best way to find out is to configure the router to use the VPN service and see if it works

Comment: So it's impossible with PTPP?

Comment: Does DD-WRT support being configured with to connect to a PTPP VPN?  Check the manual if you don't know the answer to this question.  What DD-WRT has different capabilities depending on the build configuration being used.  I am more then familar with DD-WRT and could answer my own question.

Comment: My build has PTPP client support. That's what I'm looking for, right?

Comment: Yes.  Your VPN provider will have to provide all the required configuration details.

Answer (score 0):

DD-WRT supports both PPTP and OpenVPN, both in client and in server mode. You will find the configuration windows under Services-> VPN -> PPTP client. It will look something like this, 
[image], from which you can see the info needed to complete your configuration.

It will work also if DHCP/dnsmasq services are disabled, because all it matters is that routing (and encryption) work.

Answer (score 0):

It should be just a matter of ports forwarding to your internal router (changes to the config must be made on your external router):

For **PPTP** VPN forward :

- Port 1723 TCP.
- Allow GRE traffic (if your router can block it).

For **OpenVPN** forward :

- Port 1194 UDP.

Maybe on OpenVPN you can change this at config. Don't hope to be capable on PPTP, I fear.